# How is train test split in xgboost cv specified?

Tags: python, xgboost, cross-validation, train-test-split

It is to be noted that the xgboost.cv method returns eval metrics on both train and test sets whereas the function itself takes no parameter stating which dataset to be used for training and which for testing. The `xgboost.cv` method takes only `dtrain` parameter but then how does it internally divides it into train and test split?

Comment: XGBoost CV receives a `nfold` parameter.